Is $f(x-y)g(y)$ supported in some $\sigma$-finite set?
Question
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff abelian group. Let $\mu$ be a Haar-measure of $G$. Give $G\times G$ the Radon-product $\mu\hat\times\mu$ (explained in Folland's "Real analysis" 2nd ed., Section 7.4). Let $f,g\in L^1(G)$. Then does the function
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
G\times G & \xrightarrow{F} & \mathbb C \\
(x,y) & \mapsto & f(x-y)g(y)
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
vanish outside some $\sigma$-finite Borel-set?
My attempt
It holds that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{supp}F\subseteq(\operatorname{supp}f+\operatorname{supp}g)\times(\operatorname{supp}g)\text{,}
\end{equation}
where $\operatorname{supp}f=\{x\in G:f(x)\neq0\}$. Also, $\operatorname{supp}f$ and $\operatorname{supp}g$ are $\sigma$-finite Borel-sets, since $f,g\in L^1(G)$. But the problem is that I do not know whether $\operatorname{supp}f+\operatorname{supp}g$ is contained in some $\sigma$-finite Borel-set.
